# Want to print html file in Wpf C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I have pasted code here that I have used to create an html file in wpf C# . So please help me to print that file. In below code I have created an html string and saved that html file into the path given in the code. Now I want to make this file directly go to print dialogue box, so that I can print the html file.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        string path = @"C:\Users\EACD-017\Documents\Host.html";
        string HTML =   "<html>" +
                        "<head>" +
                        "<title>"+
                         "   HOST INFORMATION " +
                        "</title>" +
                        //"    <style type=\"text/css\">" +
                        //"    .title {" +
                        //"        color: blue;" +
                        //"        text-decoration: bold;" +
                        //"        text-size: 1em;" +
                        //"    }" +
                        //"    .author {" +
                        //"       background-color:#FFECF5FD;" +
                        //"    }" +
                        //"    .table {" +
                        //"        width:100%;" +
                        //"        height:600px;" +
                        //"        border:1px;" +
                        //"        align:center;" +
                        //"    }" +
                        //"    </style>" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        "<table>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" +
                                "<img src=\"images.jpg\" style=\"width:29%;\" />" +
                                 "<span  style=\"padding-left: 18%;font-size: medium;\">HOST INFORMATION</span>" +
                            "</td>" +
                             //"<td style=\"width:18%;\">" +
                            //"</td>" +
                            //"<td style=\"font-size: 182%; text-align: center;\">" +
                            //        "    <span>CONTRACT INFORMATION</span>" +
                            //"</td>" +
                         "</tr>" +
                     "<table>" +
                        "<table style=\"margin: 0px auto; padding-top: 2%;\">" +
                        "<tr>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" +
                              "    <span>Name</span>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 84%;font-size: 110%;\">" +
                              txtName.Text  +
                          "</td>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                        "<tr>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" +
                              "    <span>Address</span>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 84%;font-size: 110%;\">" +
                              txtAddress.Text +
                          "</td>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" +
                              "    <span>City</span>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 84%;font-size: 110%;\">" +
                              txtCity.Text +
                          "</td>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                          "<tr>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" +
                              "    <span>State</span>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 84%;font-size: 110%;\">" +
                              txtState.Text +
                          "</td>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" +
                              "    <span>Zip</span>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 84%;font-size: 110%;\">" +
                              txtZip.Text +
                          "</td>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" +
                              "    <span>Phone No.</span>" +
                          "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 84%;font-size: 110%;\">" +
                              txtPhone.Text +
                          "</td>" +
                         "<tr>" +
                        "</table>" +
                        //"    <p>" +
                        //"    <span class=\"title\">{0}</span>" +
                        //"    <span class=\"author\">{1}</span>" +
                        //"    </p>" +
                        "</body>" +
                        "</html>" +
                        Environment.NewLine;



        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path,HTML);

        MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully !");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
private void PrintDocument(Uri uri)
{
    var wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    wb.DocumentCompleted += PageLoaded;
    wb.Url = uri;
}

private void PageLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender).Print();
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var url = new Uri(@"C:\Users\EACD-017\Documents\Host.html");
    PrintDocument(url);
}
```

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: still strange that you have to fall back to windows forms for printing html in WPF but this what we use too

Answer (score 0):

The following code should open IEXPLORE.exe with the given file as argument.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE.HTML";
process.Start();
```

But first, inside your HTML content you should add the following code to print on startup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```